# add custom part to v-autocomplete dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, autocomplete, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify's v-autocomplete component, and I'd like to add custom part to its dropdown (marked with red arrow on this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/lm3vjc)

This is how my component looks like, so I'd like to add that part on top of items:

```
<v-autocomplete @change='selectedSearchedCandidate' append-icon="search" :loading="loading" :filter="v => v" :items="items" :search-input.sync="search" v-model="select" flat hide-no-data hide-details return-object placeholder="Search candidates">
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ item, selected }">
        {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
    </template>
    <template slot="item" slot-scope="{ item, tile }">
        <v-list-tile-content>
            <p class='fullName'>{{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}</p>
            <p class='employer'>{{item.employer}}</p>
            <p class='phoneNumber grey--text'>{{formattedPhoneNumber(item.phoneNumber)}}</p>
        </v-list-tile-content>
    </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `prepend-item` slot. It will add, before the first item, whatever you want.

With your exemple, it should looks like this :

```
<v-autocomplete @change='selectedSearchedCandidate' append-icon="search" :loading="loading" :filter="v => v" :items="items" :search-input.sync="search" v-model="select" flat hide-no-data hide-details return-object placeholder="Search candidates">
    <v-list-tile
        slot="prepend-item"
        class="grey--text">
      {{ items.length }} candidates found
    </v-list-tile>
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ item, selected }">
        {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
    </template>
    <template slot="item" slot-scope="{ item, tile }">
        <v-list-tile-content>
            <p class='fullName'>{{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}</p>
            <p class='employer'>{{item.employer}}</p>
            <p class='phoneNumber grey--text'>{{formattedPhoneNumber(item.phoneNumber)}}</p>
        </v-list-tile-content>
    </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

[Prepend and Append slot in Vuetify Documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#slots)

---

**Edit for V1.1.0+** : Those slots are available in `v-autocomplete` and `v-combobox` as they inherit from `v-select`.

Answer (score 0):

Just modified this answer a bit. Instead of "v-list-tile-content", we can use "v-list-item-content" as the former one is giving console errors for 2.3.x and 2.4.x versions.
@toodoo